# Could the site document the differences between the implementation of vi?

Tags: discussion

With Neovim and Vim drifting apart the users migrating from one to the other have migration question.

Should the site help documenting the differences or not?

The following question: [What is Neovim, and how it is different from Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/34/23502) "document" what Neovim brings.

Could we have its counter part that "document" what Vim has and Neovim not yet?

Comment: As a gut reaction, StackExchange is a poor format for documentation (the result implied by "documenting").

Comment: But answering question is also a way to document. I believe the conflict we have here is more about the risk of opinion based reactions than poor formating. Do you see it differently?

Comment: I think this is likely to be addressed in more detail on [Eric's Q](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/10604), but in short: while my original close-reason was about opinions, I have several other reasons to think that particular question should stay closed. You'll probably have to wait for my answer there, but some ideas to get you thinking: Q&A that documents can fall out of date (something we already have to deal with); SE doesn't do well for documentation as an end-goal; the question is impractically broad (the best answer would be too long, containing all diffs), etc.

Comment: cf. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-neovim-and-how-is-it-different-from-vim for how this has played out and some of the issues that i identified above. Many answers are at least partially incorrect due to age, and the accepted answer cannot be judged as the best; it doesn't fully answer the question (and it would take much to do so). This doesn't fit well in the SE model, IME.

Comment: Although the answers have a date that indicate to the readers at which date they were valid and I have noticed users update some of their popular answers such that they remain actual. But I can follow your argument in particular when the topic could become hot.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The fact that documents can become outdated is a really weak argument to close questions, as that's true for virtually any question. Across SE sites, people keep changing their posts by adding deprecation notices, bring attention to newer methods or techniques as they become available, referring to new studies in order to provide more up-to-date evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that it could become an emotional topic although the impression I have is that the relation between the two communities is now constructive.

I'm personally interested to the answer and I think a documented answer can help at moving the two programs closer each other.